# What is the best sub string making method?

Tags: php, mysql, substring

I need to develop a search program for search specific content in the database. Then part of the matched content should be shown as a brief search result.

Here is my approaches to make the sub string for search results

1. Do the database level sub string (MySQL)
2. Do the sub string using PHP.

Search  field contains more than 500 words (minimum). Content feed via CK Editor. There are   65k rows in the table and can be grow. This table contains 3 fields of strings values use for the search (content_title, short_description, detailed_description).

What is the most efficient method to do sub string?

Comment: The database level is the right thing to go. You cannot get all the records and do a substring in PHP or any language.

Comment: Its depend on requirement, for instance if you need to show complete text after click on 'more' then you can use php as well as javascript sub string.